# Python Selenium Chrome Disable Pop Up Blocker

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

For some reason I can not figure out how to disable the pop up blocker (to allow pop up windows to work). This use to work, so I am guessing it has something to do with the new version of Chrome/Chromedriver? Below is some sample code, that I know use to work, but now when a pop up happens, I do not even see the icon in the top right, where you can allow the pop up or not. I did also try using the prefs found [here](http://tarunlalwani.com/post/selenium-disable-popup-blocker-different-browsers/) to disable the pop up blocker, but that did not work ether. If anyone has a solution, it would be much appreciated!

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

request_url = 'https://www.example.com'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(request_url)
```

Comment: What kind of popup is it? Can you share a snapshot?

Comment: A pop up as in a new window (not a new tab). So any website that opens up a new window (for example a website that has a live chat feature that opens up the chat in a new small window). I tried it on a ton of websites, with all the same outcome. Where the icon in the top right corner of the browser that you would normally click to allow the pop up, is not even showing up.