# Python script to enable chrome pop up ( Ask where to save before downloading )?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Looking for python script to actually enable/disable chrome pop up ( Ask me where to download ) option in chrome settings menu. I think it can be done with selenium but not able to find it. Help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Maybe these links will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49257433/how-to-close-yet-another-chrome-popup-using-python-selenium https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817665/python-selenium-chrome-disable-pop-up-blocker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following Code :

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.prompt_for_download': True,
         'download.directory_upgrade': True
         }

options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
```